# Jquery UI: drag new sortable list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I've found jQuery UI demo, which connects draggable and sortable plugins. (http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/sortable.html) I would like to make some kind of tree, create similar draggable emlement (yellow) that could be dragged to the old list and at once it would be a another, new sortable list (in which i can put another draggable elements)

Code i've modified:

```
$(function() {
    $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        revert: true
    });
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".sortable",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
});


<ul>
<li class="draggable ui-state-highlight">
    <ul id="sortable-2" class="sortable">
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="draggable ui-state-highlight">any element</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable" class="sortable">
    <li>first element</li>
    <li>second element</li>
</ul>
```

does not work propely. I can only put 'any element' on #sortable-2, only when #sortable-2 is on draggable unsorted list. When I move #sortable-2 list on correct position ( between first and second element I can't put 'any element' on it )

I would appreciate any answers. Thank you!